# Multiple worksheets into single Worksheets using C#

Tags: c#, excel, merge

Just started learning of Excel operation i want to merge multiple worksheets into another work sheet.
can any one help on the same using C#

Comment: Maybe this can help you to start https://medium.com/@alice.yang_10652/c-vb-net-merge-multiple-excel-workbooks-or-worksheets-into-one-b15bae13789f

Comment: No Its not working ,Its just copying only one sheet that to its lic version need to buy